# MySQL - Get the values between delimiters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have a comma separated string like

`1,2,3,4,5` or 
`1,2,3,4,5,5,8` or `1,2,2,6,6,7,8`

I want anything that is between the *third comma* and *last comma* leaving out the last element.

The result of `1,2,3,4,5` should be `4`.
The result of `1,2,3,4,5,5,8` should be `4,5,5`.
The result of `1,2,2,6,6,7,8` should be `6,6,7`.

I tried with the below. But it fails when the 3rd value is same as 1st or 2nd value.

```
SUBSTRING( LEFT(string, LENGTH(string)
    - LOCATE(',', REVERSE(string)))
    , LOCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 3), string ))
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Why do you have a comma separated string? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm.  To get rid of the last element:

```
select substr(string, 1, length(string) - substring_index(string, ',', -1) - 1)
```

Then to get rid of the first three:

```
select substr(substr(string, 1, length(string) - substring_index(string, ',', -1) - 1),
              substring_index(string, ',', 3) + 1
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is what I did to resolve. Comments are welcome.

```
select  SUBSTRING(@String,length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@String,',',3))+2, 
            (length(@String) - length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@String,',',-1))-length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@String,',',3)) -2));
```